# Stroke Patient - Android Ice Cream Sandwich TTS

Tags: text-to-speech

I have a friend who has had a stroke and can't speak any longer.  I have a Xoom with Ice Cream Sandwich (I can upgrade it anyway), and I'm just wondering if there are any built in, or inexpensive Text To Speech apps that someone can recommend.

I was thinking about using Google Translate, but unfortunately the hospital he's in doesn't have Wifi. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but this is built in to iOS 5.  Perhaps getting him a used iPod Touch hooked up to speakers would work.

Comment: I am not sure how your friend would use the TTS. Is the idea that he would input text into a device and then the TTS engine would voice it back for you to listen to? Is this for communications when you are not in the room with him. Why not use text messaging (SMS or IM)? Why is there a need to convert the text to voice? There are also products that can take a text message from a phone and use TTS to voice it back, such as SMSSpeak. [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.verzitex.android.speaksms]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems from [the API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) that Android includes a TTS engine, so I'd imagine there would be quite a few apps. I've done a [quick search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tts&c=apps), although I don't have a smartphone so I cannot vouch for the suitability, but here is one app that seems simple enough. [Text To Speech Toy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trapp.tts).